# git pull add, commit and push in java

Tags: java, git, api, maven

We have some projects which will produce some special files during maven deploy. The files will have to be put into a special git project.

Currently, we do this ourselves, but we hope it can be done automatically(by adding a maven plugin). Because this step is easily forgotten.

The question is:

Is there any API or something like that in git, that java can call it to pull, add files, commit and push. And if there is any conflict, always accept our changes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well you could have googled "git java api"

That would have returned this as the first choice

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-B%3A-Embedding-Git-in-your-Applications-JGit

> JGit
>
> If you want to use Git from within a Java program, there is a fully
>   featured Git library called JGit. JGit is a relatively full-featured
>   implementation of Git written natively in Java, and is widely used in
>   the Java community. The JGit project is under the Eclipse umbrella,
>   and its home can be found at http://www.eclipse.org/jgit. Getting Set
>   Up
>
> There are a number of ways to connect your project with JGit and start
>   writing code against it. Probably the easiest is to use Maven – the
>   integration is accomplished by adding the following snippet to the
>    tag in your pom.xml file:
>
> <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
>       <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
>       <version>3.5.0.201409260305-r</version> </dependency>
>
> The version will most likely have advanced by the time you read this;
>   check
>   http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit
>   for updated repository information. Once this step is done, Maven will
>   automatically acquire and use the JGit libraries that you’ll need.
>
> If you would rather manage the binary dependencies yourself, pre-built
>   JGit binaries are available from http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/download.
>   You can build them into your project by running a command like this:
>
> javac -cp .:org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.0.201409260305-r.jar App.java java
>   -cp .:org.eclipse.jgit-3.5.0.201409260305-r.jar App